# Error when binding JSON response into an array - React

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

I don't understand, as I am providing a Key in the `return` part of the code as below:

**`component.js`**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../about/about.css';

class About extends Component {

    state = {
        loading: false,
        data: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ loading: true })
        console.log('app mounted');
        fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=8ee8c21b20d24b37856fc3ab1e22a1e5')
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.articles, loading: false }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="about">
                {this.state.loading
                    ? "loading..."
                    : <div>
                        {this.state.data.map(post => {
                            return (
                                <div className="container about text-left mt-5" key={post.id}> 
                                        <h5>{post.title}</h5>
                                        <p>{post.description}</p>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}

                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default About;
```

I am adding a key as `key={post.id}`

Why is this error still coming?

Comment: Are you sure that post.id are uniques? Try to print all posts with console.log and show us the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you didn't store any `id` in `object` then you can't access, when Inserting data, also set `id` with some number like `Math.random()`.

Or you can use instead id, index like below!

```
**`component.js`**

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import '../about/about.css';

    class About extends Component {

        state = {
            loading: false,
            data: []
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.setState({ loading: true })
            console.log('app mounted');
            fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=8ee8c21b20d24b37856fc3ab1e22a1e5')
                .then(data => data.json())
                .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.articles, loading: false }))
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="about">
                    {this.state.loading
                        ? "loading..."
                        : <div>
                            {this.state.data.map( (post, indx) => {
                                return (
                                    <div className="container about text-left mt-5" key={indx}> 
                                            <h5>{post.title}</h5>
                                            <p>{post.description}</p>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })}

                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default About;
```

Now it should Work!

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to use indices as the key; since they are re-generated on every render, it's not as reliable of a unique identifier as an id that is always attached to a given item in an array.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the json response, `post.id` seems to not be present. Try `post.source.id`.

Note that not only should each child have a `key` prop, but it should be *unique*. If `post.id` returns `undefined` then the key would not be unique, and thus your warning.